# Scriptural sources for information on panchang, tithi, and nitya yogas

Tags: scripture, astrology, astronomy, tithi

Hindus commonly look at tithis and nitya yogas to guide the timing of their activities. [Here's an example](https://julenelouis.com/2017/10/09/nitya-yoga-panchanga/). Is there a scriptural basis of these interpretations? What scripture deals with the daily panchang?

Comment: I very vaguely associate Adi Shankaracharya (smartas) associated with panchang and their interpretations. So, perhaps you might add a smarta tag too. Personally, I have no idea about it.